# OpsWorks hogging CPU

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, cpu, aws-opsworks

I'm using `AWS Opsworks` with Chef version `11` and every time a deploy occurs I noticed a high CPU activity (a ruby process that uses a lot of CPU).

Because of that, my application breaks every time I execute a 'deploy' command.

I've reached to this thread https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=173399

and I'm wondering if such a problem still occurs with Chef version `12`.

Any idea of how to solve this issue?